# Sharepoint 2010 Organization Browser with Vacant Positions

Tags: 2010, active-directory, organization-browser

Our sharepoint 2010 uses Active Directory to populate the Org Browser, using the Manager field.

However, there are some exec. positions that are vacant, so they don't have a corresponding User in AD. What would be the best way to provide these 'dummy' users in the hierarchy?

Currently there are dummy users in AD to fulfil this purpose, but this is causing issues where other applications want to use AD to determine the genuine line manager for a User. My feeling is that AD should represent the real situation, and we somehow insert the vacant positions between AD and SP.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no solution except creating fake users in AD. 
If thats a problem, you could create a custom Org Chart.